# Existence of function satisfying given conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow[0,1]$ be continuous, strictly increasing and $f(1)=1$. Suppose further that $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$. Is there any function satisfying the above conditions?

My guess: since $f$ is strictly increasing $f$ is injective. But then this, I think, means that $f$ is bijective as the domain and codomain are equal. Furthermore, since $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous, $f([0,1])=[f(0),f(1)]$. But being a bijection then we should have $f(0)=0$ which leads to contradiction. So no such $f$ exists?

So if $f$ is not surjective, how can it be injective? And if it is, how would you show that it is surjective? I guess some kind of uncountability of real numbers must be playing some role if my guess was not correct, but I am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Is valid example? $f(0)=0$ and certainly $f(0)=0>0$ is false?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2}$

Comment: Just a pointer: the fact that an injective function $A \to A$ is surjective only applies to finite sets. For example, the function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ $n \mapsto n+1$ is injective but not surjective

Comment: $f$ is injective here only means that $f$ induces a bijection with its image.  Why would its image be its whole codomain?  Every solution (of the uncountably many) will have the property that its image is not all of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the box $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Pick a nonzero point on the y axis and join it to the point $(1,1)$ via straight line and make sure that your line has a positive slope and stays above the line $y=x$.

Comment: Thanks, I feel embarrased I couldn't think of such simple examples.. but it makes me rather curious how it is possible to produce a 1-1 correspondence between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ and still there are some of elements left in $[0,1]$ that is not mapped. I guess that is essentially what uncountability is about..